# Matrix Algebra Question (Hadamard Product)

Tags: matrix-equations, hadamard-product

How do I solve the following equation for $R$:

$(G*R)\cdot(R-H)=L$

Where:

> $R$: $n \times 1$ vector
>
> $G$: an $n \times n$ matrix
>
> $H$: $n \times 1$ vector
>
> $L$: $n \times 1$ vector

And $\cdot$ represents the element by element matrix product or the pointwise product also known as the Hadamard product $*$ represents regular matrix product.

Comment: Is one of the matrices unknown? But which? $G$, $R$, $H$ or $L$? Or do you want to know how to calculate $L$?